# Background positioning to bottom right

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an HTML page, and this css:

```
body {
color:#000;
/*BG Image is specified by javascript*/
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top left;
}
```

What you have to know, is that the page is not big enough in height, so if loaded correctly, there's a small gap between the bottom of the screen and the last line of text displayed.

I would like to make it so that the background sticks to the bottom right part of the screen, but when I change `top left` to `bottom right`, it just seems to stick to the bottom of the webpage (aka where the text ends), rather than to the bottom of the screen. I'm not sure if there is a solution, but if there is, please let me know

Comment: thats normal, if your content ends, the page ends. you need more content for  this to work like it should

Comment: @Mark Oh god, that's bad. So there's no any way to go around this?

Comment: you could give your `<body>` a height. seems to mee like overkill to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `background-size: cover` property in the body tag

this will make the background cover the whole body element

try this

```
body {
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: try prefixing the property with vendor specific i.e., -moz-

Comment: if that also doesnt work change the tag to html and add background to html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `height:100%;` in the body selector:

```
body {
  color:#000;
  /*BG Image is specified by javascript*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:top left;
  height:100%;
}
```